# extract word and fillna in specific range, between two points in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

my df:

```
A,B
hello my world, adam
i like my turbo1, nan
with love,nan
good morning, john
enev one,nan
turbo2,nan
good to you,nan
man too,emily
```

I want to extract words `turbo1` and `turbo2` to B column, and then fill all nans of those words but only until any word appears in B column in each way up and down

expected output:

```
A,B
hello my world, adam
i like my turbo1, turbo1
with love,turbo1
good morning, john
enev one,turbo2
turbo2,turbo2
goon to you,turbo2
man too,emily
```

my code:

```
df['B']=df['B'].str.extract(r'(turbo1|turbo2)').fillna(method='bfill').fillna(method='ffill')
```

problem i have is that i cannot fill nans only in this range between already existing words.

Comment: Could you explain why in `enev one,turbo2` you have `turbo2` instead of 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need replace all missing values of `NaN`s consecutive groups use:

```
m = df['B'].notna()
#for oldier pandas versions
#m = df['B'].notnull()
g = m.cumsum()[~m]
s = df['A'].str.extract(r'(turbo1|turbo2)', expand=False)

df.loc[~m, 'B'] = df['B'].fillna(s).groupby(g).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
print (df)
                  A       B
0    hello my world    adam
1  i like my turbo1  turbo1
2         with love  turbo1
3      good morning    john
4          enev one  turbo2
5            turbo2  turbo2
6       good to you  turbo2
7           man too   emily
```

**Details**:

First replace missing values by extracted values of `B`, then create unique groups only for consecutive `NaN`s and replace missing values per groups with forward and back filling:

```
print (df.assign(filled = df['B'].fillna(s),
                 cumsum = m.cumsum(),
                 g = m.cumsum()[~m]))

                  A      B  filled  cumsum    g
0    hello my world   adam    adam       1  NaN
1  i like my turbo1    NaN  turbo1       1  1.0
2         with love    NaN     NaN       1  1.0
3      good morning   john    john       2  NaN
4          enev one    NaN     NaN       2  2.0
5            turbo2    NaN  turbo2       2  2.0
6       good to you    NaN     NaN       2  2.0
7           man too  emily   emily       3  NaN
```

Comment: i am receiving an error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'notna'

Comment: @sygneto - then use `notnull()` instead `notna()`